# Different toolbar colors for different activities android

Tags: android, android-studio, colors

How would I go about having different toolbar/navigation bar colours for different activities. I've tried creating two custom themes but I just can't get them to inherit these different themes.

[Acitivity 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJW20.png) - Currently blue theme

[Activity 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBEoM.png) - Want this to have a grey theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andrewfinlay.vectorcalculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThemeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_theme"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the theme in the manifest of the desire activity, so it would look something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/YourGrayTheme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `AndroidManifest` where you add the activity, you can also specify the theme of the activity. If you already have the custom themes, it's as simple as adding

`android:theme="@style/MyBlueTheme"` and `android:theme="@style/MyGreyTheme"`

Comment: In the `AndroidManifest` it says `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">` Yet still turns out to be blue.

Comment: So AppTheme.NoActionBar probably has no values set for the actionbar, as its title suggests. In that case it probably falls back on your app theme. Can you post the contents of your AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a your own `theme` that just includes a color. Then you will be able to set all of the properties you need to that theme, thus changing the color.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this in your `onCreate`.

```
setTheme(R.style.YourAppTheme);
```

You can create many themes in your `res/values/styles.xml`

One example :

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <!-- you can customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```